# "A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column." on a persisted computed column (EntityFramework DB first)

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, sql-server-2012, entity-framework-6

I've implemented a simulated table inheritance construct in my SQL-Server based on the article [Implementing Table Inheritance in SQL Server](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/implementing-table-inheritance-in-sql-server).

Besides the fact to use simple 1 to 0...1 relationships you create another constraint to a type table that lists all possible children types of the base table as explained in the article in the paragraph "Modeling One-to-Either Constraints".

Every of your child tables contains a TYPE field that has a ComputedColumnSpecification with a persisted number that represents the ID of the type in the type table. Due the fact the TYPE field is part of the constraint, it will make sure only one child can be created to the base data set.

For better understanding I've created a sample database that is used to describe the problem with a matching ASP.NET solution. To replicate the issue at your local environment, create a database called "PLAYGROUND" before executing this script:

```
USE [PLAYGROUND]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[USER] ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[USER](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TYPE__ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Enabled] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Username] [nvarchar](32) NOT NULL,
    [Password] [nchar](32) NOT NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_USER] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[NATURAL_USER] ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[NATURAL_USER](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TYPE]  AS ((1)) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
    [BirthDate] [date] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_NATURAL_USER] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[JURIDICAL_USER] ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[JURIDICAL_USER](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TYPE]  AS ((2)) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
    [CompanyName] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [RegistrationNo] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_LEGAL_USER] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[USER_T] ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[USER_T](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TYPE] [nvarchar](32) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_USER_T] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Index [IX_USER] ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[USER] ADD  CONSTRAINT [IX_USER] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [Username] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Index [PK_USER_TYPE] ******/
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [PK_USER_TYPE] ON [dbo].[USER]
(
    [ID] ASC,
    [TYPE__ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON

GO
/****** Object:  Index [IX_USER_T] ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[USER_T] ADD  CONSTRAINT [IX_USER_T] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [TYPE] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON

GO
/****** TYPE DATA ******/
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[USER_T] ON 
GO
INSERT [dbo].[USER_T] ([ID], [TYPE]) VALUES (2, N'JURIDICAL_USER')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[USER_T] ([ID], [TYPE]) VALUES (1, N'NATURAL_USER')
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[USER_T] OFF
GO
/****** Contraints ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[JURIDICAL_USER]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_JURIDICAL_USER___USER] FOREIGN KEY([ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[USER] ([ID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[JURIDICAL_USER] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_JURIDICAL_USER___USER]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[JURIDICAL_USER]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_JURIDICAL_USER___USER___TYPEVALIDATION] FOREIGN KEY([ID], [TYPE])
REFERENCES [dbo].[USER] ([ID], [TYPE__ID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[JURIDICAL_USER] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_JURIDICAL_USER___USER___TYPEVALIDATION]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[NATURAL_USER]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_NATURAL_USER___USER] FOREIGN KEY([ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[USER] ([ID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[NATURAL_USER] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_NATURAL_USER___USER]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[NATURAL_USER]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_NATURAL_USER___USER___TYPEVALIDATION] FOREIGN KEY([TYPE])
REFERENCES [dbo].[USER_T] ([ID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[NATURAL_USER] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_NATURAL_USER___USER___TYPEVALIDATION]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[USER]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_USER___USER_T] FOREIGN KEY([TYPE__ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[USER_T] ([ID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[USER] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_USER___USER_T]
GO
USE [master]
GO
ALTER DATABASE [PLAYGROUND] SET  READ_WRITE 
GO
```

The table `USER` is the base table and the tables `NATURAL_USER` and `JURIDICAL_USER` are its children. `USER_T` is the type table of `USER`.

Now, in my ASP.NET application using the EntityFramework 6 I try to create a new user the following way:

```
using (PLAYGROUNDEntities model = new PLAYGROUNDEntities())
{
    USER user = new USER();
    user.Username = "admin";
    user.Password = "RANDOMHASH#123456";
    user.Email = "admin@example.org";

    user.NATURAL_USER = new NATURAL_USER();
    user.NATURAL_USER.BirthDate = new DateTime(1980, 01, 01);

    model.USER.Add(user);
    model.SaveChanges();
}
```

And on `model.SaveChanges();` I get the exception:

> A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column. Column: 'TYPE'.

Sample solution: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/55589036/zzzOther/Playground.zip (the sample code is in the `Page_Load`of the `Default.aspx.cs`.

I understand, the EntityFramework tries to set the column field and fails, because it's store generated (persisted). This even happens when I set `user.NATURAL_USER.TYPE = 1;`.

I tried to override `OnModelCreating` to attach my own rule and define the both `TYPE` columns as `Computed`, but `OnModelCreating` is never called, because I do **EDMX-after** and I want to stick to this.

So, this entity model is generated based on the database and I'd like to keep it this way, plus I don't want to edit any code when I update my model again, every time.

Also, I think the table inheritance concept is very well implemented on the database layer, because it does not use triggers. I want to keep it trigger-free.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Why don't you just use EF with its own inheritance (TPT or TPH)? Do you have a project constraint about using DB First?

Comment: @bubi TPT or TPH approaches are only inheritance systems on EF and still allow to bypass it on the database by using plain SQL. TPT/TPH require me to build associations in the designer after re-creating the EDMX file. Please correct me if I'm wrong here.

Comment: TPT and TPH are approaches [strictly] related to Code First. If you are working on an existing database (DB First + EDMX) is not a good approach. Your case is TPH (single table + discriminator field) but if DB + EDMX is a constraint standard EF TPH is not a good approach.

Comment: @bubi Right, this is correct. It would be the solution on code-first, though. I have to stick to database-first, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made a terrible mistake when implementing the approach, but it worked before. I messed up the constraint `FK_NATURAL_USER___USER___TYPEVALIDATION`, accidentally.

It should have been build like the `FK_JURIDICAL_USER___USER___TYPEVALIDATION` constraint.

The EF is able to handle the persisted columns. The problem was it tried to write to the PK of `[USER_T]` that should not be apart of the constraint at all.

I'm sorry for all people who wasted time on this.

Answer (score 2):

I know nothing about EF, but I'd create your `TYPE` columns as normal columns, not calculated, not persisted.

Then I'd set their default value to the required value and add a `CHECK` constraint to make sure that it can't be changed.

The rest of your T-SQL script where your set up foreign keys remains the same.

For example, for `NATURAL_USER` it would look like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[NATURAL_USER](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TYPE] [int] NOT NULL,
    [BirthDate] [date] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_NATURAL_USER] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[NATURAL_USER]  WITH CHECK 
ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_NATURAL_USER] CHECK  (([TYPE]=(1)))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[NATURAL_USER] 
CHECK CONSTRAINT [CK_NATURAL_USER]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[NATURAL_USER] 
ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_NATURAL_USER_TYPE]  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [TYPE]
GO
```